# Unable to get user id from facebook using php sdk?

Tags: php, facebook

I am using facebook php sdk in zend. i am not getting user id even i have logged in facebook in another tab. Please help me to fix this issue.

```
           $facebook = new \Facebook(array(
          'appId'  => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
          'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET,
          'cookie' => true,
           ));

           $user = $facebook->getUser();
           echo $user;
```

when i am using above code `$user` return `0` some times.

Comment: i have tried all possibilities still getting 0

Answer (score 0):

remove the  \   before facebook. Correct way will be:

```
       $facebook = new Facebook(array(
           'appId'  => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
           'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET,
           'cookie' => true,
       ));
```

Let me know if this helped.
kind regards.

Comment: i am working on Facebook sdk with ZEND2. For that i have to Create facebook object in this way, since included in `index.php` of public folder